# css hover to change opacity value of other element

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="logoWrap">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/OBFbjSK.png">
    <p class="logoDesc">this is img desc</p>
</div>
```

I want to avoid using javascript, is it possible to change the value of other element using :hover? if possible I want to add transition.

http://jsfiddle.net/UH2Aq/

Comment: You want to change opacity on which element ? when the mouse is over which element ?

Comment: [Wow, that was hard...](http://jsfiddle.net/UH2Aq/3/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean that you want the hover on the logoWrap to make the logoDesc appear?

If so:
http://jsfiddle.net/wildandjam/emELN/

```
.logoWrap:hover .logoDesc{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Then, if you want, you can add a CSS3 transition, to make it more fluid.

Answer (score 3):

Same answer with transition : http://jsfiddle.net/UH2Aq/1/

```
.logoDesc{

 transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    opacity : 0;
}

.logoWrap:hover .logoDesc {
    opacity: 1;
}
```